# Can $\frac{1}{z}$ be expressed as a Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can the complex function $\frac{1}{z}$ be expressed as a Laurent series, around $z=0$, over the whole complex plane? I have tried re-writing it as $\frac{-1}{1-(z-1)}$. However I can only expand this under the condition that $\left | z-1 \right |\geq 1$, which won't satisfy $\left | z \right |\geq 0$.

It's probably worth noting that I'm actually trying to calculate the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z-i}$ around $z=i$ and was merely using $w=z-i$ as a substitution.

Comment: $1/z= z^{-1}$ ...

Comment: it is already a Laurent series, it is its own...

Comment: $1/z$ already is a Laurent series (as @TorstenSchoeneberg comments).

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg Oh. So would this imply that 1/(z-i) is also a Laurent series?

Comment: Well the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z-i}$ around $i$ is already $\frac{1}{z-i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to calculate in either case. 
The Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z-i}$ around $z=i$ is in the form:

\begin{align}\cdots+\frac{a_{-n}}{(z-i)^n}+\frac{a_{-n+1}}{(z-i)^{n-1}}+\cdots+\frac{a_{-1}}{z-i}+a_0+a_1(z-i)+a_2(z-i)^2+\cdots\end{align}

with all coefficients equal to zero except $a_{-1}=1$.